The proposition associated with a set
Given a set $U$ and a set $A \subseteq U$, is there an accepted symbol for the proposition $p$ over the universe $U$ such that for each $x \in U$, $p(x)$ is the assertion that $x \in A$? (The symbol $p_A$, perhaps?)
The symbol $\chi_A$ is often used to denote the function from $U$ to $\{0,1\}$ such that $\chi_A$ takes the value 1 on $A$ and the value 0 elsewhere; $1_A$ is also used to signify this function. But I'm reluctant to use these symbols to denote what I've called $p_A$ above since propositions over a universe are culturally different from functions. (On a technical level the distinction becomes less clear, especially if we conflate 1 with truth and 0 with falsity.)
Regardless of what symbol is used, could this proposition be called the "characteristic proposition" of $A$ (by way of analogy with the phrase "characteristic function")? Or would this create a collision with an existing meaning of this phrase? I suppose "indicator proposition" is a possibility too.

What's wrong with just "$x\in A$" itself? (Or "$A(x)$" for even more brevity.)

@NoahSchweber, re, I think the first runs into the trouble that it seems that the question is about a name for $p$, not $p(x) = x \in A$. I guess one could call it, suggestively but idiosyncratically, the $(\in A)$ proposition. (Perhaps, in analogy with the sometime notation $\equiv_m$ in place of $\equiv\pmod m$, we could call it $\in_A$?) For the second, we run into the problem that $A$ could be a set or a proposition, which is surely more of an abuse of language than using $\chi_A$ for both the function and the proposition!

@LSpice As long as $x$ is a variable as opposed to an element of $U$, I don't see the issue. (Although I guess the OP used $x$ for an element of $U$ rather than a variable.)

I personally like $\in_A$ but I think my students will feel more comfortable with $p_A$, so I plan to go with that nonce-notation (where "the nonce" = "this week") unless there's a standard notation already in use.
